# Log-statements and collection-functions (map, filter)

Tags: kotlin, logging

I have code that combines and deduplicates two arrays. When duplicates are found, it drops the corresponding items of the second array.

```kotlin
fun combineAndDedupe(fromMainSupplier: List<Book>, fromSecondarySupplier: List<Book>): List<Book> {
    val isbnsFromMain = fromMainSupplier.map { it.isbn }
    return fromMainSupplier + fromSecondarySupplier.filter { it.isbn !in isbnsFromMain }
}
```

I have been asked write a log-statement if any books have been filtered out, listing all affected ISBN's. I am struggling to implement this in a way that feels "Kotliny". It's too verbose, too long, too hard to read. Is there a more elegant way? I often encounter this problem where the original code is reasonably elegant, but once you add a log-statement, you are writing Java 7 again.

One of my more verbose attempts:

```kotlin
private fun combineAndDedupe(fromMainSupplier: List<Book>, fromSecondarySupplier: List<Book>): List<Book> {
    val isbnsFromMain = fromMainSupplier.map { it.isbn }
    val isbnsFromSecondary = fromSecondarySupplier.map { it.isbn }
    val isbnsToRemove = isbnsFromSecondary.filter { it in isbnsFromMain }
    if (isbnsToRemove.isNotEmpty()) {
        val isbnsString = isbnsToRemove.joinToString(",")
        logger.info(
            "Removing books from secondary supplier that are already present in main supplier: ${isbnsString}"
        )
    }
    return fromMainSupplier + fromSecondarySupplier.filter { it.isbn !in isbnsToRemove }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier with the `intersect` function.

```
private fun combineAndDedupe(fromMainSupplier: List<Book>, fromSecondarySupplier: List<Book>): List<Book> {
    val intersection = fromMainSupplier.intersect(fromSecondarySupplier)
    if (intersection.isNotEmpty()) {
        logger.info(
            "Removing books from secondary supplier that are already present in main supplier: ${intersection.map(Book::isbn).joinToString()}"
        )
    }
    return fromMainSupplier + (fromSecondarySupplier - intersection)
}
```

The above assumes that Books are equal if their ISBNs are equal. If that's not true, you must extract the ISBN. Here's one way to do it (that assumes the input lists do not have duplicate ISBNs in them:

```
private fun combineAndDedupe(fromMainSupplier: List<Book>, fromSecondarySupplier: List<Book>): List<Book> {
    val intersection = fromMainSupplier.map(Book::isbn)
        .intersect(fromSecondarySupplier.map(Book::isbn).toSet())
    if (intersection.isNotEmpty()) {
        logger.info(
            "Removing books from secondary supplier that are already present in main supplier: ${intersection.joinToString()}"
        )
    }
    return (fromMainSupplier + fromSecondarySupplier ).distinctBy(Book::isbn)
}
```

Some describe "Kotlinly" as being as close to functional programming as possible, but that's not true. Functional programming is just an option in Kotlin. I would say "Kotlinly" just means using the tools it gives you to write readable code where it's easy to follow the logic.

Comment: Small nit: The two input-array don't contain any true duplicates, only "soft" duplicates where the `.isbn` is the same. Other properties, such as price, are usually different. This it the reason why it's important that the items of the "first" array are always kept, and of the "second" are dropped, when they are dupes.

Comment: @MartinJ.H. OK, I added another way to do it. I don't see a way to avoid all the mapping if you need to compare them by the inner property.

Comment: Hmm... How does the `distinctBy` remove items only fro the secondarySupplier? Is that guaranteed or an implementation detail?
In any case, thank you, I slightly changed how the intersection is computed in your first solution, and now it works for me! The array-`-` was the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Actually I got it backward (just swapped the order). The order isn't an implementation detail. The [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct-by.html) say that only the first instance of each item is retained. I had the order backward because maps work the other way around (adding an already existing key to a map replaces the old item, but adding an already existing item to a set keeps the old item).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tenfour04's solutions, I was able to rework my approach into:

```kotlin
fun combineAndDedupe(fromMainSupplier: List<Book>, fromSecondarySupplier: List<Book>): List<Book> {
    val isbnsFromMain = fromMainSupplier.map { it.isbn }
    val booksToRemove = fromSecondarySupplier.filter { it.isbn in isbnsFromMain }
    if (booksToRemove.isNotEmpty()) {
        val isbnsString = booksToRemove.joinToString(",") { it.isbn }
        logger.info(
            "Removing books from secondary supplier that are already present in main supplier: $isbnsString"
        )
    }
    return fromMainSupplier + (fromSecondarySupplier - booksToRemove.toSet())
}
```

The `.toSet()` in the last line is not strictly necessary, but it was suggested by my linter.